# How to assign the values from the line edit of Qt to the variables

Tags: qt, variables

suppose I have the line edit in my Qt window and if I have to assign value to the variables from the line edit of the window, what should be the changes in code.
my mainwindow.ccp is:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
  QMainWindow(parent),
  ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
 ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
  delete ui;
}
```

and mainwindow.h is:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~MainWindow();

private:
  Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

here the entered input from the line edit should assign the value for variable V1 and V2 means

```
V1 = variable1
V2 = variable2
```

and these variables V1 and V2 later we can use in any class as global varible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your variable type is string:

```
QString str = ui->lineEdit->text();
```

If your variable type is for example integer:

```
int val = ui->lineEdit->text().toInt();
```

You can also assign it to a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use global variables. But obtaining the input from QLineEdits is

```
QString s = this->ui->lineedit->text();
```

Comment: Avoid using `this` too. `this` is part of scoping rules.

Answer (score 0):

if the variable in global than,

```
 v1=ui->lineEdit_1->text();
 v2=ui->lineEdit_2->text();
```

If the variables are local to that function than,

```
QString v1=ui->lineEdit_1->text();
QString v2=ui->lineEdit_2->text();
```

If the variables are int...

```
 v1=ui->lineEdit_1->text().toInt();
 v2=ui->lineEdit_2->text().toInt();
```